# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" with basic bank account program

Tags: java

Main:

```
     package A3;
      public class myAccounts {
       public static void main (String []args){
        bankAccount.enterbalance();
        bankAccount.menu();
    }
}
```

class:

```
    package A3;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class bankAccount {
    public static Double balance;

    public static void enterbalance() {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter your starting balance");
        Double balance = Double.parseDouble(input);
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu(){
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Menu:  1.Deposit  2.Withdraw  3.Check balance  4.Quit");
        int menuchoice = Integer.parseInt(input);

        while (menuchoice != 4){
            if (menuchoice == 0 || menuchoice > 4){
                System.out.println("Invalid selection, select again.");
            }
            else if (menuchoice == 1){
                bankAccount.deposit();
            }
            else if (menuchoice == 2){
                bankAccount.withdraw();
            }
            else if (menuchoice == 3){
                bankAccount.checkbalance();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void deposit(){
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter deposit amount");
        Double deposit = Double.parseDouble(input);
        balance =  balance + deposit;
        menu();
    }

    public static void withdraw(){
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter withdrawal amount");
        Double withdrawal = Double.parseDouble(input);
        balance = balance - withdrawal;
        menu();
    }


    public static void checkbalance (){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your balance is $" + balance);
        menu();
     }
}
```

My problem comes up in the checkbalance() method...looking for some direction. Can the problem be solved this way or do I need to change my program significantly?

and here's the full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at A3.bankAccount.deposit(bankAccount.java:42)
at A3.bankAccount.menu(bankAccount.java:27)
at A3.bankAccount.enterbalance(bankAccount.java:14)
at A3.myAccounts.main(myAccounts.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1):

The balance variable has been declared twice. Once at the class level and another time within the `enterbalance()` method.

Your code should read

```
balance = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

instead of

```
Double balance = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Double variables, not double. Double is a wrapper reference type for the primitive type double, much like Integer is a wrapper for the int type. When you declare a reference variable without assigning it a value, it is assigned null. When you try to add null value to another Double, `balance =  balance + deposit;`, you get your NullPointerException or NPE.

One solution is to give your Double variable an initial value so that nothing is null:

```
public static Double balance = 0.0;
```

Better is to use only double types, not Double since double is a primitive and cannot be null. Note that double fields are by default initialized to 0.0, but you might as well make it explicit:

```
public static double balance = 0.0;
```

As a side recommendation:

- Capitalize the names of your classes so that they conform to Java naming rules, making your code easier for others (us!) to understand.
- Are you sure that all these fields and methods should be declared static? It looks like you'd be far better off using non-statics for most fields and methods, excepting your main method of course.

Comment: Thank you!

Are you sure that all these fields and methods should be declared static? It looks like you'd be far better off using non-statics for most fields and methods, excepting your main method of course.

I thought so too, but can't figure out how to call non static methods from static ones...

Trying to +1 to both of you but it says I have too low of a rating to do so

Comment: if I am trying to call a method that is not static from a method that is, I get an error message

Comment: Create a BankAccount instance in your main method, and call non-static methods off of it.